# Override syntax highlighting in vim file

Tags: vim

I am trying to override a markdown file syntax by placing the following file `md.vim` in my `after/syntax` directory. `md.vim` contains the following code:

```
syntax region mdNote start=/\<\cNOTE\>/ end=/\r/
highlight def link mdNote Todo
```

I have tested that the code works by sourcing it directly but when I launch a file with an extension `.md`, the `mdNote` syntax does not work. For example, given the following markdown file:

```
# Main Heading 


Note: This is a note
```

If I put the cursor inside the word `Note` and get the syntax group, I get:

`mkdNonListingItemBlock` which comes from the [plasticboy/markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) plugin that I have installed.

Does anyone know why my syntax file is not working?

Comment: Why don't you add those lines to that other plugin?

Comment: This is an option but not ideal as it would be overwritten each time I update the plugin, my change will be overwritten.

Comment: True but then I would still have to incorporate any updates made to the plugin into my forked version as and when they occur. Its a solution but not one without ongoing maintenance. I would like to try and get the override working as it seems the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Markdown files will reference the `markdown.vim` file in `after/syntax`. To get this information for any file, you can open a file of the desired format and run `:set syntax?`. Rename your file to `markdown.vim` and it should work.

Comment: just realised that this only works if the word `note` is on the first line only. On any other line, the syntax group still shows `mkdNonListingItemBlock` so ` plasticboy/markdown` must be overwriting. Any ideas?